# Can't install pgadmin4 on Ubuntu 21.10 / SOLVED with how to make a terminal command alias

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, 21.10, pgadmin

Alright folks, going a bit crazy here.

I'm running Ubuntu 21.10 impish off of an external ssd. Things are working well, trying to install pgadmin4 by following the guide here:

https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-apt/

namely, adding the extra the PPA , updating the apt repository, and then installing with apt:

```
# Setup the repository
#

# Install the public key for the repository (if not done previously):
sudo curl https://www.pgadmin.org/static/packages_pgadmin_org.pub | sudo apt-key add

# Create the repository configuration file:
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/$(lsb_release -cs) pgadmin4 main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgadmin4.list && apt update'

#
# Install pgAdmin
#

# Install for both desktop and web modes:
sudo apt install pgadmin4

# Install for desktop mode only:
sudo apt install pgadmin4-desktop

# Install for web mode only: 
sudo apt install pgadmin4-web 

# Configure the webserver, if you installed pgadmin4-web:
sudo /usr/pgadmin4/bin/setup-web.sh
```

^ note these are the official instructions from pgadmin.org, which says it has support for `Ubuntu 21.10 (Impish, from v6.2)` (I don't know what the v6.2 means, but whatever)

It appears that everything installs, and then when I try running `$ pgadmin4` , nothing happens

I tried manually specifying amd64 architiecture and even switching to the LTS focal endpoint using `$ sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgadmin4.list`, changing

`deb https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/impish pgadmin4 main`

to

`deb [arch=amd64] https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/focal pgadmin4 main`

Still no joyy....what am I missing here?  and Ideally, how would I do it all in an automated script?  Setting up a new system, and wrestling with stuff like this is never enjoyable.

UPDATE:  Turns out it was installed (I would have seen it if I had just pushed the Super key and searched for it).  But to make a terminal command, you have to look for the path to the executable and make a custom alias. Accepted answer gives a good description of how you might generally do that

Comment: I would be asking this of the pgadmin.org people.

Comment: @David fair enough, emailing the pgadmin support mailing list now, but just wondering if any other users of 21.10 can replicate this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking into installed files by

> ```
> dpkg -S pgadmin4 | grep pgadmin4$
> ```

giving the following clues

> ```
> pgadmin4-desktop: /usr/pgadmin4/bin/pgadmin4
> pgadmin4-web, pgadmin4-desktop, pgadmin4-server: /usr/pgadmin4
> ```

It also should be noted that PgAdmin 4 desktop file in `/usr/share/applications/pgadmin4.desktop` contains `Exec=/usr/pgadmin4/bin/pgadmin4`.

So after following [README](https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/README) you can run PgAdmin 4 using `/usr/pgadmin4/bin/pgadmin4` command.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @N0rbert -- feel a little silly in retrospect. I had set up it to work on WSL2 on the Windows side, and I forgot it didn't just come for free.  Appreciate you also explaining some tools that I can use if I need to poke around installation  stuff in the future!

Comment: how did you learn about the -S switch of dpkg?  I just checked the man file and  didn't find an explanation for it

Comment: See https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/dpkg/dpkg.1.en.html#S about `-S`.